# Can I use the Dropbox API to Download Files from a regular link?

Tags: python, dropbox-api

I would like to download files from a link a received to Dropbox. I created an API token, but I'm not sure the type of link I received is sufficient.

Using these [docs](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.sharing_get_shared_link_file), I tried retrieving the file but am receiving the following error:

```
ApiError: ApiError('', GetSharedLinkFileError('shared_link_access_denied', None))
```

Here's my code:

```
import dropbox
dbx = dropbox.Dropbox("{ACCESS TOKEN}")
dbx.users_get_current_account()

download_path = '{LOCAL PATH}'
url = 'https://www.dropbox.com/sh/{DROPBOX FOLDER}?dl=0'
dbx.sharing_get_shared_link_file_to_file(download_path, url, path=None, link_password=None)
```

I tried replacing the `sh` with `s` based on [this](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-Support-Feedback/Downloading-shared-file-python-API/td-p/324175), no success.

Do I have the link I need? Is it something in the code?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox shared links with `"/sh"` refer to folders. These links are valid for use with `sharing_get_shared_link_file_to_file`, but since they refer to folders and not individual files, you do need to specify the `path` parameter to indicate which file in the linked folder you want.

Here's a working example:

```
import dropbox

dbx = dropbox.Dropbox("{ACCESS TOKEN}")

file_path = '/dahlia_l.jpg'
download_path = 'download.jpg'
url = 'https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ljrkl8kbddx8n1c/AAACNrUwqPSVv27oh97QhN0Za?dl=0'
res = dbx.sharing_get_shared_link_file_to_file(download_path, url, path=file_path)

print(res)
```

Comment: I tried this method, but the downloaded file is always corrupted. The original size of the file on dropbox is 16.2 GB, but the downloaded file is only 13.4 GB. How can we fix this?

Comment: @ShanAli If you're running in to any issues with the Dropbox API, please open an API ticket here with all of the relevant details: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/contact